# How to put formatter value on the piecharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a piechart of highchart plugin,here the value is showing outside of the chart,but as per my requirement outside value should be removed and only value(2.6% etc..) should be shown above each particular sections. I tried with formatter but it was not working. Here is my code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: It's unclear which values you want to see and which values you'd like hidden.  A marked-up image would be helpful.

Comment: All value should be seen..but instead of showing outside of chart it should be seen on the chart of particular section

Answer (score 0):

`dataLabels.distance` property is what you're looking for:

```
  dataLabels: {
    distance: -50,
    (...)
  }
```

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.distance

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3p7qdsnf/